# Word for application that is both sender and receiver

Tags: single-word-requests

I am developing a software application that acts as a sender as well as a receiver. What is a single word for this?

This is a peer application running on two different machines, sending data to and receiving data from its peer.

Comment: Can you give some more details?  There might be a more precise word that we can suggest if we know more about the role of this program.

Comment: This is a peer application running on two different machines, sending/receiving data to-and-fro with its peer.

Comment: .......Bipolar?

Comment: How about hermaphrodite? :-)

Comment: Most network applications both send and receive, that is the nature of communication. In a client/server system the client usually makes requests and the server services them, replying with requested data or replying that data was or wasn't received. Since you are creating a peer application, each instance of your application is *a peer* so could be named as such, e.g. *MyApplicationPeer*.

Comment: Coin your own. Call it a chatterbox.

Comment: I'm a Sr. Software Engineer in the IT field, and I will agree with @MarkBooth on this one. However, in a network structure, you may refer to something like this simply as a "node" by default.  But I think "peer" is suffice for application development whereas "node" may be more of a networking term.

Comment: How about naming it based on what it's for rather than how it does it?  E.g. mirror, backup, share, cache.

Comment: Someone else asked this a few years later and a great answer was posted, `Correspondent` (not to be confused with `Corespondent`) -- https://english.stackexchange.com/q/369828/33559

Answer (score 40):

The word used in the radio/telecomms industry is [*transceiver*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transceiver).

Comment: +1 but I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate word to use for software. Where it is, it's [almost exclusively](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+transceiver) used to refer to some sort of radio controlling software: infrared, RF, wireless, Bluetooth. An exception may be SMPP or SFP.

Comment: There was a time when sender and receiver used to refer to radio, too. Before that they used to refer to paper letters being sent back and forth. Nothing wrong with repurposing a word for software, especially if the definition of the word is so clear-cut.

Comment: @Lunivore I disagree. As a software developer, if I heard another developer talk about a "transceiver," it would give me pause and make me think a radio handset was somehow involved. "What does a radio have to do with your peer-to-peer application?" The word is just never used in developer speak.

Comment: @Phil, both Darren and I are also software developers. I'm fairly well known for helping development teams communicate more effectively with the business, using plain English, examples of system behavior and metaphors that they can understand (see "BDD"). This is an appropriate and useful metaphor, and if it drives out some of the "developer speak", so much the better.

Comment: Transceivers are definitely not limited to radio - they were very common in IT, alternatively called "media converters" - bidirectional devices that convert data between two types of network, say, AUI and 10baseT ethernet (without doing any extra work like handshakes or authentication like modems and wifi accesspoints do)

Answer (score 32):

> Peer.

Obviously, you'll need more than one word when first introducing the application. Thereafter, *peer* should cover it.

Comment: +1 That's probably the most appropriate description for a node in a network made up of equally capable participants.

Comment: I'm quite fond of *transceiver*, but just calling it *peer* is a pretty good choice too. Either should work.

Comment: My only qualm with this answer is that it implies there are other nodes networked to it that act in the exact same way. Still, +1.

Answer (score 12):

In distributed systems, this is usually referred to as a [node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28networking%29).

Comment: Clients and servers are often referred to as `node`s, so in this instance, I think `peer` is more appropriate than 'node',  as it is a tighter definition, closer to the requested intent.

Comment: "node" is used in non-network related structures as well (binary tree etc.).

Answer (score 4):

I would ignore the fact that it both sends and receives and focus on what its purpose is.  The fundamental distinction between a client and a server is that human beings interact with clients. If it has a user-interface and does what a human being tells it to do, it's a `client`. If it performs services only (or primarily) for other software components, it's a `server`.

(The X Window System does this the other way around, calling the 'server' the component that accepts connections and the 'client' the component that makes them. It confuses the heck out of everyone.)

If you want to stress the fact that the relationship is many-to-many and not the usual many clients to one server, use `peer`. If you feel that's too specific and want something more generic, use `node`.

Answer (score 3):

The word *manager* is sometimes used in software for a component that both sends and receives.

> This is a peer application running on two different machines, sending/receiving data to-and-fro with its peer.

This is similar to BitTorrent software, usually called a *client*, regardless of the fact it sends as well as receives.

Comment: I also work in the software industry, and 'manage' strikes me as an adequate name for something that sends and receives. It 'manages' the messages going to and from somewhere.

Comment: I disagree. Manager is too vague a term for a software component. It could refer to any component that does something with another component. See Clean Code for a chapter on Naming which talks about avoiding the word Manager <http://www.amazon.com/dp/0132350882/?tag=stackoverfl08-20>.

Answer (score 3):

Very generically, *transactor* might be suitable. *Broker* could also be appropriate in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

> [Servent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servent) (coined by Gnutella)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servent):

> In general a servent is a peer-to-peer network node, which has the functionalities of both a server and a client.

Comment: An interesting portmanteau, but rather obscure. plus, how widely is it used? It looks like it was coined by Gnutella and failed to propagate much further. Certainly most google search hits are just miss-spellings of servant.

Comment: Not very widely used, no, but i think it's clever enough to start using.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a *broker* since it deals with input and output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word, full-duplex.

From wikipedia:

> A full-duplex (FDX), or sometimes double-duplex system, allows communication in both directions, and, unlike half-duplex, allows this to happen simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think this is precise enough to be the single  descriptor the OP is looking for.  As your comment says, full-duplex only implies /simultaneous/ transmit/receive, not that it is capable of both transmitting and receiving.  A half-duplex system is still capable of transmitting and receiving, but can only do one at once.

Answer (score 1):

[Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) might fit.

Answer (score 0):

*Muxer* (an abbreviation of *multiplexer*) is sometimes used as a name for an application like this.

Comment: muxing is more about combining things than transmitting/receiving

Answer (score 0):

This could be referred to as a *switch*.

Answer (score 0):

If this application were surreptitious and malicious, it would be a "man-in-the-middle."

Comment: This answer made me smile

Answer (score 0):

The link would be [bidirectional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional).

Answer (score -2):

It could be described as a *hub*.

Comment: Hub implies a centralised nature rather than a distributed one.