# Is there a word that encompasses both "receiving" and "sending"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word for application that is both sender and receiver](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/word-for-application-that-is-both-sender-and-receiver)

In the sentence *"There are many ways to receive and send information."*,  is there a word that can replace *"receive and send"*?

I was thinking of the word **transmit**: *"There are many ways to transmit information."*,

But transmit seems to convey only a one-way direction instead of a two-way direction.

Is there a word that encompasses the meaning of both "receiving" and "delivery" ?

Comment: @waiwai933 If I had more rep, I'd vote to reopen this question.  The presumed duplicate asks for a word for an _application_ that both transmits and receives (a noun).  This question is asking for a gerund that encompasses the act of transmitting and receiving.

Comment: @JoelBrown Normally, I'd agree with you, but in this case, the OP specifically requested it be closed as a dupe (in a now-deleted comment) after someone else pointed that question out.

Comment: @waiwai933 Maybe OP was shy and didn't want to fight. This question isn't a duplicate of the other one, and should be unmarked.

Answer (score 9):

You might have a look at

> **exchange**
>   *noun*
>   an act of giving one thing and receiving another (esp. of the same type or value) in return

The verb form is probably what you're looking for.