# What's a word that means both 'source' and 'sink'?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the sense of: it can emit data but it can also receive data. Or water. Or gas. Or whatever.

Comment: Also: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/46867/48571 and https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66546/48571