# What is the generic term for “sender” and “receiver”?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

*Fruits* is the generic term for *apples* and *pears.*

What is the generic term for *sender* and *receiver* in an abstract context?

In my special case I have users and servers who both can send and receive messages. I want to create a class to handle general logic for both of them.

Comment: A [transceiver](https://www.google.com/search?q=transceiver+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Z2mGWN_THuzX8gew0q7IAQ) is a _device_ that can send and receive.

Comment: Are you trying to name a subclass of 'user' that is a superclass for the two separate classes 'sender' and 'receiver'?

Comment: A communications ***endpoint*** can both transmit and receive messages.

Comment: @Jim: hmm are there any synonyms for that?

Comment: In the pre-digital age these might have been *correspondents*.

Comment: Transceiver is a device that does both, not a person. The person is context dependent. On a phone they're callers. I guess here they are texters?

Comment: **Transactant** ("one who transacts") would be the human analog of **transceiver**.  It is a little broader than just sender+receiver, but it might fit what you need.

Comment: Agents, parties, endpoints, actors, contacts, points, connections.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes". See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Interlocutors...look it up.

Comment: That's not about English… it might be about whatever OS or protocols you're working with and in English, the obvious Answer would be "correspondents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Communication* **endpoint** seems to fit best in my case.

Answer (score 6):

From a native speaker:

Perhaps you are looking not for a single item that sends and receives, but one label that applies to either party. Use **party** to mean either end of the communication.  You can introduce the connection between the label 'party' and both parties on the line by writing "When either party, the send or receiver, is active ..."

Comment: Yes, and if the OP wants to name a software class used to define them he could use _transaction party_.

Answer (score 4):

Devices that can both *send* and *receive* are known as [*transceivers*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transceiver):

> **transceiver** noun [ C ]
>
> a piece of equipment that can send out and receive electronic signals:
>
> - It has an infrared transceiver which can be used to exchange files with similarly equipped machines.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: This would be my favorite if I had only servers or things that communicate. I don't think that this would be applicable for a 'user'.

Comment: @jordan_conelli - Users aren’t instances of a class. Users interact with objects via a user interface.

Answer (score 4):

When servers or users send and receive information they communicate.. so in that role perhaps they are:

***communicators***

> [Oxford Dictionary's definition of communicator](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/communicator)
>
> com·mu··ni·ca·tor
>   kəˈmyo͞onikādər/
>   noun
>   plural noun: communicators
>
> 1.
>   a person who is able to convey or exchange information, news, or ideas, especially one who is eloquent or skilled.
>   "a gifted communicator"
>
> 2.
>   an apparatus used to exchange information between individuals, ships, planes, etc.
>   "it'll send a signal to your hand-held communicator"

Answer (score 0):

***Hub***, perhaps, - *the effective centre of an activity, region, or network*.  There can be multiple hubs in a network...