# Hypernym for “sender” and “recipient” (in terms of a shipment)

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What is a hypernym for "sender" and "recipient" in terms of a shipment?

I am searching for a name for a name of member of a class that can be both sender and recipient of a shipment.

Comment: I'm not sure how appropriate it is for your (unspecified) need, but in an IT context, one possibility might be to call them "endpoints".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Sorry for not being specific. I do not mean an "endpoint" to receive and send shipments. I mean the persons/organizations who actually receive/send the shipment to each other.

Comment: I think this will be difficult. You are asking for a word which encompasses 'buyer and seller'. "Shipment participators" ?

Comment: `Party` should work. (Both parties were satisfied.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/369828/17956

Comment: @Jim I have seen this question before. But in that question "receiver" and "sender" are meant in a very technical way.

Comment: @FelixJordan - That's why I said ***possibly*** and did not CV as duplicate.  But thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center says that picking names for computer software thingies is out of scope for our site.

Comment: @tchrist I just got helped by this question and it's not about computer software thingies.

Comment: TIL of Hypernym and Hyponym, thank you!

Comment: @Alex I got helped too, but this question was definitely for programming purposes, hence, "for a name of member of a class" ... ironically, that's why I'm here too, programming a field that can belong to recipients or senders, `correspondent` is the perfect name, glad I could find this!

Answer (score 3):

Such a person would be a correspondent if sending and receiving letters. For shipments a customer might be appropriate. They would return shipments they refused and receive others.

Comment: Amazed I wasn't able to come up with this on my own, thank you Google and thank you Elliot!

Answer (score 0):

"[Traffic Clerk](https://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes435071.htm)", occupational code 43-5071 in the Bureau of Labor Statistics Occupational Employment Statistics definition.

> Verify and maintain records on incoming and outgoing shipments. Prepare items for shipment. Duties include assembling, addressing, stamping, and shipping merchandise or material; receiving, unpacking, verifying and recording incoming merchandise or material; and arranging for the transportation of products. Excludes "Stock Clerks and Order Fillers" (43-5081) and "Weighers, Measurers, Checkers, and Samplers, Recordkeeping" (43-5111).